# the following arguments are required: -m/--model, -o/--output

Tags: python

I am attempting to run a GoogLeNet code, but then get this error:

```
C:\Users\JG\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe C:/Users/JG/PycharmProjects/GoogLeNet/googlenet_cifar10.py
2022-05-14 14:47:18.996037: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_110.dll
usage: googlenet_cifar10.py [-h] -m MODEL -o OUTPUT
googlenet_cifar10.py: error: the following arguments are required: -m/--model, -o/--output

Process finished with exit code 2
```

But I do not know where the issue is coming from. I know that the following argument is listed.

```
# construct the argument parser
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-m", "--model", required = True, help = "path to output model")
ap.add_argument("-o", "--output", required = True,
    help = "path to output directory (logs, plots, etc.)")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())
```

Comment: What do you not understand in the error message and/or the arguments?

Comment: @Holt - I am new to python and trying to run a GoogLeNet code. So due to being introduced to python. I don't understand all errors. When I run the code now, it is showing the following:

2022-05-14 15:07:47.634108: W tensorflow/core/kernels/data/generator_dataset_op.cc:107] Error occurred when finalizing GeneratorDataset iterator: Failed precondition: Python interpreter state is not initialized. The process may be terminated.
         [[{{node PyFunc}}]]

Comment: These are *command line* arguments. They don't go in the source code, they go on the command line when you're starting the program.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - I did it run it from the command line. That is what happens after

Comment: Yes, but you need to put the `-m` and the `-o` and their arguments  *on the command line*. The failure you're getting is explicitly spelling out that your command line didn't include mandatory elements.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide those two arguments for the script to run. As it says in the [README](https://github.com/meng1994412/GoogLeNet_from_scratch) file:

```py
python googlenet_cifar10.py --model output/minigooglenet_cifar10.hdf5 --output output
```

The part of the script that you have posted does two things. (1) It requires arguments `-m` and `-o` from the user and (2) it parses those arguments for later use.

Comment: Where I do provide those arguments? Sorry for the dumb question, I am new to Python.

Comment: @Josh No problem. Change `C:\Users\JG\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe C:/Users/JG/PycharmProjects/GoogLeNet/googlenet_cifar10.py
` to `C:\Users\JG\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe googlenet_cifar10.py --model output/minigooglenet_cifar10.hdf5 --output output`.

Comment: Hmm, it looks the same as what I initially posted?

Comment: 2022-05-14 16:16:31.636744: W tensorflow/core/kernels/data/generator_dataset_op.cc:107] Error occurred when finalizing GeneratorDataset iterator: Failed precondition: Python interpreter state is not initialized. The process may be terminated.
         [[{{node PyFunc}}]]

Comment: @Josh, "failed precondition" is _not_ what you originally posted. If you successfully reached a new and different problem, your original problem is solved.

Comment: @Josh Indeed, this is a different problem. Search SO for a solution. If there is none, then I suggest that you ask a new question.